# Python: How to ignore an exception and proceed?

Tags: python, exception

I have a try...except block in my code and When an exception is throw. I really just want to continue with the code because in that case, everything is still able to run just fine. The problem is if you leave the except: block empty or with a #do nothing, it gives you a syntax error. I can't use continue because its not in a loop. Is there a keyword i can use that tells the code to just keep going?

Answer (score 843, accepted):

```
except Exception:
    pass
```

[Python docs for the pass statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements)

Comment: except Exception: pass # important not to swallow other exceptions!

Comment: This will catch SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt and other things that you probably don't want to catch.

Comment: It won't catch KeyboardInterrupt. For example:
`while True:`
`try:
`f = open('filedoesnotexist.txt')`
`except:`
`pass`

KeyboardInterrupt stops and exits the code.

Comment: @ChthonicProject a bare `except` will catch any exception, including a KeyboardInterrupt, but only if it happens inside the `try`. In your example there, a KeyboardInterrupt can occur before the `try` or inside the `except`, where it won't be caught. If you run an example like `while True:` `try: pass` `except: pass`, you'll find that the KeyboardInterrupt gets caught just about 50% of the time. If you `time.sleep(1)` inside the `try`, you'll find that it gets caught almost every time.

Comment: This stops executing after the first exception. What I just want to totally ignore all exceptions, eg `print('this'); 1/0; print('this too');`? And say I have 10 commands, don't want to write 10 try except pass blocks.

Comment: One also can use `...` (ellipsis) in `except` clause instead of `pass`: `except: ...`

Comment: `…` is just an expression like `1` or `True` or `None` or `NotImplemented`, all of which can be used as quasi-nops (and `pass` still beats them because it produces exactly 0 (zero) opcodes for the Python VM to execute (in CPython that is)).

Comment: How does this compare to try: xxx() finally: pass?

Answer (score 345):

#### Generic answer

The standard "nop" in Python is the `pass` statement:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception:
    pass
```

Using `except Exception` instead of a bare `except` avoid catching exceptions like `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` etc.

#### Python 2

Because of the last thrown exception being remembered in Python 2, some of the objects involved in the exception-throwing statement are being kept live indefinitely (actually, until the next exception). In case this is important for you and (typically) you don't need to remember the last thrown exception, you might want to do the following instead of `pass`:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception:
    sys.exc_clear()
```

This clears the last thrown exception.

#### Python 3

In Python 3, the variable that holds the exception instance gets *deleted* on exiting the `except` block. Even if the variable held a value previously, after entering and exiting the `except` block it becomes **undefined** again.

Comment: This is a better answer than the one that was accepted because it uses "except Exception:" instead of just "except:" which as others have pointed out will improperly swallow other things that you don't want to catch like SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: +1 It also clears the error which is important when running unittests and expecting exceptions

Comment: Note that `exc_clear` was removed in python 3. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#index-22. For some ways to address this in Python 3 see here: https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575187/3140992 for quickly ignoring multiple exceptions

Comment: One also can use `...` (ellipsis) in `except` clause instead of `pass`: `except Exception: ...`

Answer (score 304):

There's a new way to do this coming in Python 3.4:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(Exception):
  # your code
```

Here's the commit that added it: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/406b47c64480

And here's the author, Raymond Hettinger, talking about this and all sorts of other Python hotness (relevant bit at 43:30): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go

If you wanted to emulate the bare `except` keyword and also ignore things like `KeyboardInterrupt`—though you usually don't—you could use `with suppress(BaseException)`.

Edit: Looks like `ignored` was renamed to `suppress` before the 3.4 release.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this solution... I guess the idea is we've replaced 3 lines with just 1 (the try, except, and pass are all merged into one.) The main thing I object to is how this introduces a new keyword that seems to vindicate something you probably shouldn't be doing... it seems like you should always at least log exceptions you're catching...

Comment: When an exception is raised will it continue the code after the try/catch or whatever is outside of the `with` block?

Comment: This is equivalent to wrapping your code in a `try...catch: pass`, so if an exception is raised inside the block, execution will continue after the end of the block.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare What if I said, I'll give you an integer, but sometimes I'll give it to you in a singleton tuple, and I won't tell you when I do one or the other; now your job is to always give me back the integer? Perhaps you would appreciate being able to write something like `with suppress(TypeError): return data[0]` (longer example: http://pastebin.com/gcvAGqEP)

Comment: @Navin Python can't just pretend that an exception didn't exist. Suppose I have a statement like `y = f(x) * g(x)`, and then `f(x)` raises an exception. Even if Python ignores it, `f(x)` never returns a value, so there's no way for Python to assign a value to `y`. The designers could've said "assume a value of None" or "skip statements containing any expression that failed to evaluate," but that would end up being very confusing. Using `try` blocks to group statements that fail together keeps things simple.

Comment: @JackO'Connor Fair enough. I was hoping there would be a way to replace an expressions with None if it raises an exception.

Comment: Can it be done inline? For instance something like `supress(myFunc, suppressedException, returnValueOnFailure)`?

Comment: @JeromeJ you can't do that with `suppress` directly, because it's a context manager. (For details about how context managers work, see here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) But it would be pretty simple to define your own `callCatchingExceptions` function that used `suppress` or an ordinary `try` block on the inside, if you wanted.

Comment: FYI, django revert the use of `with suppress(Exception)` on 2017-09 , because try/except performs better. Check this commits [Reverted "Fixed #27818 -- Replaced try/except/pass with contextlib.su…](https://github.com/django/django/commit/6e4c6281dbb7ee12bcdc22620894edb4e9cf623f)

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
try:
    blah()
except:
    pass
```