# How to properly ignore exceptions

Tags: python, exception, try-except

When you just want to do a try-except without handling the exception, how do you do it in Python?

Is the following the right way to do it?

```
try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Weird that nobody mentioned it until now (I did in my answer), but for this specific function, you can just do `shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)`. This won't apply for most functions, however.

Comment: Important read when thinking about ignoring exceptions: **[Why is “except: pass” a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327/216074)**

Comment: Imagine doing this in real life.  try: get_cash('$1000') except: pass # meh, it will probably be fine

Comment: Not work for me:
I made a checksum function that generates expected overflows:

try:     a1[3]=a1[0]+a1[1]+a1[2]
except:      pass

That generates error at the output window:
d:\jlope\Phyton\Prue\prue12_ftdi:33: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ushort_scalars

Answer (score 1219, accepted):

```
try:
    doSomething()
except Exception: 
    pass
```

or

```
try:
    doSomething()
except: 
    pass
```

The difference is that the second one will also catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit` and stuff like that, which are derived directly from `BaseException`, not `Exception`.

See documentation for details:

- [`try` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#try)
- [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions)

However, it is generally bad practice to catch every error - see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: Note that StopIteration and Warning both inherit from Exception as well. Depending on your needs, you may want to inherit from StandardError instead.

Comment: This is true, but if you're not careful, you can run into subtle bugs (especially if you're doing something other than passing on StopIteration).

Comment: -1, `try: shuti.rmtree(...) except: pass` will crudely suppress any errors (even if you misspell `shutil` resulting in a `NameError`) - at the very least do `except OSError:`

Comment: This answer, while informative, is missing a crucial information - you should never catch an exception this way. Instead, you should always try to catch just the exceptions you care about, otherwise you will have nightmares when hunting down trivial bugs, hidden by your generic "except"s. See dbr's answer for more info. (I know this was not the original question - but anyone looking for this will just take your snippet and use it as is)

Comment: Jabbas answer should be accepted as for versions later than Python 3.4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677839/7162168

Comment: https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/

Answer (score 165):

It's generally considered best-practice to only catch the errors you are interested in. In the case of `shutil.rmtree` it's probably `OSError`:

```
>>> shutil.rmtree("/fake/dir")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/fake/dir'
```

If you want to silently ignore that error, you would do:

```
try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Why? Say you (somehow) accidently pass the function an integer instead of a string, like:

```
shutil.rmtree(2)
```

It will give the error *"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"* - you probably don't want to ignore that, which can be difficult to debug.

If you *definitely* want to ignore all errors, catch `Exception` rather than a bare `except:` statement. Again, why?

Not specifying an exception catches *every* exception, including the `SystemExit` exception which for example `sys.exit()` uses:

```
>>> try:
...     sys.exit(1)
... except:
...     pass
... 
>>>
```

Compare this to the following, which correctly exits:

```
>>> try:
...     sys.exit(1)
... except Exception:
...     pass
... 
shell:~$
```

If you want to write ever better behaving code, the [`OSError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) exception can represent various errors, but in the example above we only want to ignore `Errno 2`, so we could be even more specific:

```
import errno

try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
        # ignore "No such file or directory", but re-raise other errors
        raise
```

Comment: `shutil.rmtree` is not the best example, because you would just use `ignore_errors=True` for that function..

Comment: Really like this answer, but you did not explain how you went from `Errno 2` to `errno.ENOENT`.. Could be helpful for a lot of people. ;)
See [Python Standard Errno System Symbols](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/errno.html) for more info.

Answer (score 122):

First I quote the answer of Jack o'Connor from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574730/python-how-to-ignore-an-exception-and-proceed). The referenced thread got closed so I write here:

"There's a new way to do this coming in Python 3.4:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(Exception):
    # your code
```

Here's the commit that added it: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/406b47c64480

And here's the author, Raymond Hettinger, talking about this and all sorts of other Python hotness: https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=43m23s

My addition to this is the Python 2.7 equivalent:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ignored(*exceptions):
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions:
        pass
```

Then you use it like in Python 3.4:

```
with ignored(Exception):
    # your code
```

Comment: That is nice. Even better to do it that way \n
sp=suppress(Exception)\n
with sp:\n
    # your code

Answer (score 118):

> When you just want to do a try catch without handling the exception, how do you do it in Python?

It depends on what you mean by "handling."

If you mean to catch it without taking any action, the code you posted will work.

If you mean that you want to take action on an exception without stopping the exception from going up the stack, then you want something like this:

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    handle_exception()
    raise  #re-raise the exact same exception that was thrown
```

Answer (score 60):

For completeness:

```
>>> def divide(x, y):
...     try:
...         result = x / y
...     except ZeroDivisionError:
...         print("division by zero!")
...     else:
...         print("result is", result)
...     finally:
...         print("executing finally clause")
```

Also note that you can capture the exception like this:

```
>>> try:
...     this_fails()
... except ZeroDivisionError as err:
...     print("Handling run-time error:", err)
```

...and re-raise the exception like this:

```
>>> try:
...     raise NameError('HiThere')
... except NameError:
...     print('An exception flew by!')
...     raise
```

Also, multiple exception types can be handled as a parenthesized tuple:

```
try:
    i_might_fail()
except (ValueError, TypeError) as ex:
    print('I failed with: ', ex)
```

...or as separate except clauses:

```
try:
    i_might_fail()
except ValueError:
    print('handling a ValueError...')
except TypeError:
    print('handling a TypeError...')
```

...see the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 46):

> ## How to properly ignore Exceptions?

There are several ways of doing this.

However, the choice of example has a simple solution that does not cover the general case.

### Specific to the example:

Instead of

```
try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except:
    pass
```

Do this:

```
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
```

This is an argument specific to `shutil.rmtree`. You can see the help on it by doing the following, and you'll see it can also allow for functionality on errors as well.

```
>>> import shutil
>>> help(shutil.rmtree)
```

Since this only covers the narrow case of the example, I'll further demonstrate how to handle this if those keyword arguments didn't exist.

## General approach

Since the above only covers the narrow case of the example, I'll further demonstrate how to handle this if those keyword arguments didn't exist.

### New in Python 3.4:

You can import the `suppress` context manager:

```
from contextlib import suppress
```

But only suppress the most specific exception:

```
with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```

You will silently ignore a `FileNotFoundError`:

```
>>> with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
...     shutil.rmtree('bajkjbkdlsjfljsf')
... 
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

> As with any other mechanism that completely suppresses exceptions,
>   this context manager should be used only to cover very specific errors
>   where silently continuing with program execution is known to be the
>   right thing to do.

Note that `suppress` and `FileNotFoundError` are only available in Python 3.

If you want your code to work in Python 2 as well, see the next section:

### Python 2 & 3:

> When you just want to do a try/except without handling the exception,
>   how do you do it in Python?
>
> Is the following the right way to do it?
>
> ```
> try :
>     shutil.rmtree ( path )
> except :
>     pass
> ```

For Python 2 compatible code, `pass` is the correct way to have a statement that's a no-op. But when you do a bare `except:`, that's the same as doing `except BaseException:` which includes `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `SystemExit`, and in general, you don't want to catch those things.

In fact, you should be as specific in naming the exception as you can.

Here's part of the Python (2) [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), and as you can see, if you catch more general Exceptions, you can hide problems you did not expect:

```
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
      +-- StopIteration
      +-- StandardError
      |    +-- BufferError
      |    +-- ArithmeticError
      |    |    +-- FloatingPointError
      |    |    +-- OverflowError
      |    |    +-- ZeroDivisionError
      |    +-- AssertionError
      |    +-- AttributeError
      |    +-- EnvironmentError
      |    |    +-- IOError
      |    |    +-- OSError
      |    |         +-- WindowsError (Windows)
      |    |         +-- VMSError (VMS)
      |    +-- EOFError
... and so on
```

You probably want to catch an OSError here, and maybe the exception you don't care about is if there is no directory.

We can get *that* specific error number from the `errno` library, and reraise if we don't have that:

```
import errno

try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except OSError as error:
    if error.errno == errno.ENOENT: # no such file or directory
        pass
    else: # we had an OSError we didn't expect, so reraise it
        raise
```

Note, a bare raise raises the original exception, which is probably what you want in this case. Written more concisely, as we don't really need to explicitly `pass` with code in the exception handling:

```
try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except OSError as error:
    if error.errno != errno.ENOENT: # no such file or directory
        raise
```

Answer (score 14):

I needed to ignore errors in multiple commands and [fuckit](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) did the trick

```
import fuckit

@fuckit
def helper():
    print('before')
    1/0
    print('after1')
    1/0
    print('after2')

helper()
```

Comment: +1 because You definitely made my day because inside this source code you can learn some extremely useful things like modifying the live stack

Answer (score 11):

```
try:
      doSomething()
except Exception: 
    pass
else:
      stuffDoneIf()
      TryClauseSucceeds()
```

FYI the else clause can go after all exceptions and will only be run if the code in the try doesn't cause an exception.

Comment: Finally a good explanation of `else` in this context. And to add that `finally` will **always** run after any (or no exception).

Answer (score 11):

> When you just want to do a try catch without handling the exception,
>   how do you do it in Python?

This will help you to print what the exception is:( i.e. try catch without handling the exception and print the exception.)

```
import sys
try:
    doSomething()
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python, we handle exceptions similar to other language, but the difference is some syntax difference, for example,

```
try:
    #Your code in which exception can occur
except <here we can put in a particular exception name>:
    # We can call that exception here also, like ZeroDivisionError()
    # now your code
# We can put in a finally block also
finally:
    # Your code...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a try-except but still another way to handle exceptions if object-oriented programming is your thing:

```
class MyExceptionHandler:

    def __enter__(self):
        ... # Do whatever when "with" block is started
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        return True
```

And then to the actual code:

```
with MyExceptionHandler():
     ... # Code that may or may not raise an exception
     shutil.rmtree(path)
```

How this works?

- `__enter__` is run when entering the `with` block.
- `__exit__` is run when exiting the `with` block

  - This should return `True` to silence the possible exception.
  - This should return `None` (or something which is considered False) to not silence the potential exception.
  - The exception type, actual exception and its traceback are passed as (positional) arguments. You can use these to determine what to do.

As a final note, prefer try-except. This may be useful if you need more abstraction than usual.

Comment: Elegant but not obvious, but actually cool

Answer (score -5):

I usually just do:

```
try:
    doSomething()
except:
    _ = ""
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you replace `_ = ""` with `pass`.

Comment: And if you are using this fragment in code that has the variable `_` assigned before this block, if an exception occurs, then after this block the variable will have changed value.