# scrapy error when crawling over a link

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have a problem which is `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

the code is working good on shell but not on code.

Comment: You must be mixing tabs and spaces, which you shouldn't do in python. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python

Comment: I always here about his problem, i don't know what is it. do you know that i should remove all the spaces? i don't have tabs here

Comment: Replace all tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: Looking at the code you pasted in the question, your "car['ATitle']" line starts with 2 TABs, replace these with 2 x 4-spaces

Comment: In future if beginner or learning python, Always enable showing invisible characters in your text editor so that you can see no tabs or spaces are being mixed.

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: @Abhishek note pad plus plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Indentation Error because you are mixing tabs or spaces anywhere in file. So you should convert all tabs to 4 spaces

or

If you want you can use tabs only but don't mix with spaces or else you will get Indentation Error again.

Also you said you keep mixing spaces and tabs so i advice you to enable showing Invisible characters so that you know you aren't mixing tabs and spaces.

In **Notepad++** you can do that by :

```
View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters

or

View->Show Symbol->Show White Space and Tab
```

If you use **Sublime Text 2**, you can do this:

Go to Preferences -> Settings- default

Change

```
"draw_white_space": "selection"

 to

 "draw_white_space":"all"
```