# Show whitespace characters in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, whitespace

Is it possible to show whitespace characters, like the space character, in Visual Studio Code?

There doesn't appear to be an option for it in the `settings.json` (though it is an option in *Atom.io*), and I haven't been able to display whitespace characters using CSS.

Answer (score 941, accepted):

**VS Code 1.6.0 and Greater**

As mentioned by [aloisdg below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037865/2814830), `editor.renderWhitespace` is now an enum taking either `none`, `boundary` or `all`. To view all whitespaces:

```
"editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
```

**Before VS Code 1.6.0**

Before 1.6.0, you had to set `editor.renderWhitespace` to `true`:

```
"editor.renderWhitespace": true
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this only for selected characters, like Sublime's `"draw_white_space": "selection"` option ?

Comment: @noio Not yet, but it's on its way [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1477)

Comment: But this only shows whitespace at the beginning and end of lines?

Comment: @drzaus, `"editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary"` will be the beginning and end of lines where as `"deitor.renderWhitespace": "all"` will show all whitespace. 

@AlexanderGonchiy, I've found it useful to open file>preferences>user settings(or workspace settings) and using 'find' in the default settings folder to look for what I need.

Comment: For `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` is the one that works

Comment: File -> Preferences -> Settings. Search for 'whitespace'. Under 'Editor: Render Whitespace' there is a dropdown to select your new setting. (v1.13.2)

Comment: @noio, see my answer below the `selection` option is added in v1.37 (released in early August, 2019).

Comment: As of December 2019, you can do `"editor.renderWhitespace": "selection",` and it will only render white spaces when selected.

Comment: An alternative: in **Keyboard Shortcuts** (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S) you'll find through searching _Render Whitespace_ the`editor.action.toggleRenderWhitespace` binding (e.g. assign it to Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B) which will allow to turn it ON/OFF while coding.

Comment: @JackChance The `boundary` option is not limited to the beginning and end of lines (although it is poorly named), for instance, multiple spaces between words are also rendered.

Comment: @Mark updating an answer according to *original sources* doesn't mean it is a copy from another answer. If you feel like that please flag for a moderator attention.

Comment: @revo That could ultimately make moot all other answers to many, many questions if eventually their content was incorporated into the first answer.  Are you citing something for the "original sources"  idea?

Comment: @Mark Sorry but I don't think so. This question got many answers over years which mostly could be merged into one. They are just referring to different versions of a software with an slightly different behavior. They do not contain different programming or algorithmic solutions. So if I update my answer according to new versions of the mentioned software I'm doing good because I want to maintain my answer for future readers too. Otherwise I could post a new answer whenever a new version comes out. Hence the edit is valid. I'll rollback.

Comment: If you really feel that way, you should make this answer a wiki-answer.

Comment: @Mark I have no intention to make it a community wiki. Once again if you feel this is wrong bring it up in meta.

Comment: no longer works with version 1.66.2

Comment: Doesn't `\r` and `\n` count as whitespace? Even when I change this setting to "all", it doesn't show them. [There is an extension to show these](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=medo64.render-crlf&ssr=false), but it has [a major limitation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=medo64.render-crlf&ssr=false#review-details): `For a file with mixed endings, it just renders the default symbol for every line ending regardless, making it useless to perceive the differences in line endings throughout the file.` See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/127

Answer (score 284):

#### UPDATE (December 2023)


To show whitespace characters in ***VSCode >1.85***, you can do `View -> Appearance -> Render Whitespace`.

[image]

Comment: `View > Appearance > Render Whitespace` now

Comment: I had to turn it off and on before it worked (beforehand it was already on)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Confirmed.

Answer (score 110):

## UPDATE (June 2019)

For those willing to **toggle whitespace characters** using a keyboard shortcut, you can easily add a *keybinding* for that.

In the latest versions of Visual Studio Code there is now a user-friendly graphical interface (i.e. no need to type JSON data etc) for viewing and editing all the available keyboard shortcuts. It is still under

> *File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*  (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

There is also a search field to help quickly find (and filter) the desired keybindings. So now both adding new and editing the existing keybindings is much easier:

[image]

Toggling *whitespace characters* has no *default* keybinding so feel free to add one. Just press the <kbd>+</kbd> sign on the left side of the related line (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or double click anywhere on that line) and enter the desired combination in the pop-up window.

And if the keybinding you have chosen is already used for some other action(s) there will be a convenient warning which you can click and observe what action(s) already use your chosen keybinding:

[image]

As you can see, everything is very intuitive and convenient.
Good job, Microsoft!

---

## Original (old) answer

For those willing to **toggle whitespace characters using a keyboard shortcut**, you can add a custom binding to the *keybindings.json* file (*File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*).

*Example*:

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
        "command": "editor.action.toggleRenderWhitespace"
    }
]
```

Here I have assigned a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to toggle invisible characters, you may of course choose another combination.

Comment: My Visual Studio uses `ctrl+e ctrl+s` by default. For combo shortcuts like this one you need to put a space between the two combinations, not a comma.

Comment: Quick reminder that keyboard actions like this one can also be searched and run through the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`), in case you prefer not having to set and remember a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 78):

**Show whitespace characters in Visual Studio Code**

change the `settings.json`, by adding the following codes!

> the file path is `.vscode/settings.json` in your project root folder.

```json
    // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
    {
        "editor.renderWhitespace": "all"
    }
```

**just like this!**
(PS: there is no **"true"** option!, even it also works.)
[image]

Answer (score 47):

*** Update August 2020 Release *** see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/104310

`"editor.renderWhitespace": "trailing"`  // option being added

```
Add a new option ('trailing') to editor.renderWhitespace that renders only 
trailing whitespace (including lines with only whitespace).
```

---

*** Update February 2020 Release *** see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90386

In v1.43 the **default value will be changed to `selection`** from `none` as it was in v1.42.

```
"editor.renderWhitespace": "selection"  // default in v1.43
```

---

Update for v1.37: adding the option to render whitespace within selected text only.  See [v1.37 release notes, render whitespace](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_37.md#render-whitespace-in-selection).

> The `editor.renderWhitespace` setting now supports a `selection` option. With this option set, whitespace will be shown only on selected text:

```
"editor.renderWhitespace": "selection"
```

and

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {    
  "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#fbff00"
}
```

[image: demo of whitespace render in selection]

---

Comment: If you want to make it a little less present vs code also accepts the alpha channel so #fbff0040 would also be valid making the dots more transparent

Comment: Loved that little gem that sets the color--very helpful for a cohort of mine who couldn't see the grey dots, LOL

Answer (score 35):

Just to demonstrate the changes that `editor.renderWhitespace : none||boundary||all` will do to your VSCode I added this screenshot:
[image].

Where <kbd>Tab</kbd> are `→` and <kbd>Space</kbd>are `.`

Comment: P.S. color schema is not part of change (I have an extra plugin for this)

Comment: Plugin can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow&showReviewDialog=true

Answer (score 29):

1. Open User preferences. Keyboard Shortcut: `CTR + SHIFT + P` -> Preferences: Open User Settings;
2. Insert in search field **Whitespace**, and select **all** parameter 
   [image]

Comment: Also, for VS Code 1.45 (on OSX), the default was "selection".

Comment: This is the best answer! It actually explains how to get to the section and what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

## All Platforms (Windows/Linux/Mac):

It is under **View -> Render Whitespace**.

> ⚠️ Sometimes the menu item shows that it is currently active but you can's see white spaces. You should **uncheck and check again** to make it work. It is a known bug

---

#### A note about the macOS 

In the mac environment, you can search for any menu option under the **Help** menu, then it will open the exact menu path you are looking for. For example, searching for **white**space result in this:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 21):

It is not a `boolean` anymore. They switched to an `enum`. Now we can choose between: `none`, `boundary`, and `all`.

```
// Controls how the editor should render whitespace characters,
// posibilties are 'none', 'boundary', and 'all'.
// The 'boundary' option does not render single spaces between words.
"editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
```

You can see the original diff on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/51833724ae0d237ea5bb2a4918c4fc16b8e811a0#diff-6728189afcd9d7e37ec62aa3e7e67056L772).

Comment: It is also possible to install an extension called Trailing Spaces to show only the trailing ones.

Comment: It nowadays supports also `trailing` and `selection`. See also: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/163213

Answer (score 8):

In order to get the diff to display whitespace similarly to `git diff` set `diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace` to false.  `edit.renderWhitespace` is only marginally helpful.

```
// Controls if the diff editor shows changes in leading or trailing whitespace as diffs
"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
```

To update the settings go to

> File > Preferences > User Settings
>
> **Note for Mac users: The Preferences menu is under Code not File. For
>   example, Code > Preferences > User Settings.**

This opens up a file titled "Default Settings".  Expand the area `//Editor`.  Now you can see where all these mysterious `editor.*` settings are located.  Search (CTRL + F) for `renderWhitespace`.  On my box I have:

```
// Controls how the editor should render whitespace characters, posibilties are 'none', 'boundary', and 'all'. The 'boundary' option does not render single spaces between words.
"editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
```

To add to the confusion, the **left** window "Default Settings" is not editable.  You need to override them using the **right** window titled "settings.json".  You can copy paste settings from "Default Settings" to "settings.json":

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
     "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
     "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
}
```

I ended up turning off `renderWhitespace`.

Answer (score 5):

The option to make whitespace visible now appears as an option on the View menu, as "Toggle Render Whitespace" in version 1.15.1 of Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 5):

Hit the F1 button, then type "Toggle Render Whitespace" or the parts of it you can remember :)

I use vscode version 1.22.2 so this could be a feature that did not exist back in 2015.

Comment: this works! But it only toggles between 'all' and 'none', skipping the 'boundary' option.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to offer this suggestion as a side note.
If you're looking to fix all the 'trailing whitespaces' warnings your linter
throws at you.
You can have VSCode automatically trim whitespaces from an entire file using
the keyboard chord.
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>X</kbd> *(by default)*

I was looking into showing whitespaces because my linter kept bugging me with whitespace warnings. So that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023), whitespace and tab reresentation won't be impacted by style/colors, as they are today, like reported [in issue 49462](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/49462):

> Before 1.75:
>
> [image: current situation]

[PR 168732](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/168732) proposes a new `experimentalWhitespaceRendering` setting:

- `svg`: Use a new rendering method with svgs
- `font`: Use a new rendering method with font characters
- `off`: Use the stable rendering method

It is available now (Dec. 2022) in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).