# how to fix pretier/prettier error in nuxtjs

Tags: eslint, nuxt.js, prettier

I already try a lot of things and read a topic about prettier/prettier and eslint error when using nuxtjs this is my first time using nuxt but I can't seem to make it work. I try to install `npm i eslint-config-prettier` but nothing happen, I tried this code too `npm run lint -- --fix` it fix the code but when I add a new code it still give me the error.

I try this topic but still not solved:

[eslint-and-prettier-battle-for-supremacy](https://medium.com/@daveed_kz/eslint-and-prettier-battle-for-supremacy-f2657c9cf950)

[add a lint:fix command to package.json](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/642)

this is the screenshot I got:

[This the error message that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKFFC.png)

this is my carousel code:

```
<template>
  <h1>Test boy</h1>
</template>

<style scoped>
  h1 {
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: What text editor do you use? Does it show invisible spaces `..` ?

Comment: Based on the screenshot of the error message, looks like that prettier is pointing to some distinct spaces `..` that your editor is not showing them. If you are using Atom try `Preferences > Editor > Show Invisibles`.

Comment: I'm using visual studio code for the editor, @emare as for `..` it not showed

Comment: can you try adding `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` to your vs code config file and see if it shows whitespaces even in other files? more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code/40037865

Comment: I tried it and now i see there is a lot of bullet like `..` in my code

Comment: great. now remove the unnecessary ones and see if you still get those three lint errors