# Can you tell me how can i get this thing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Can you tell me how can I get this arrow thing in my VS Code?

Comment: Do you know what the arrow codes are called or what they represent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show whitespace characters in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl + shift + p` this will open up a settings and type `whitespace` and choose `Toggle Render Whitespace`

[image]

this will give you something like this:

[image]

you can undo by pressing same settings option.