# How to show '\n' and '\t' characters in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging a laravel app and I need to know if any of these characters ( `\n` `\t` ) are present.

Previously VS Code did show them, now it does not:

[image]

Is there any way to enable this again?

---

I'm using Xdebug + VS Code.

Comment: There is a setting to `Render Whitespace` - it doesn't seem to show anything for newlines though.

Comment: Related: [Show whitespace characters in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Visual studio code "delegated" this escape to the debugger, I have spoken to the developer of xDebug and they told me they aren't escaping anything on their side, it seems a problem of vs code and this should be an option for the end-user not the debugger.

**there's no current way of doing this atm on this date**

Answer (score 0):

This might help?

```
  // Controls how the editor should render whitespace characters.
  //  - none
  //  - boundary: Render whitespace characters except for single spaces between words.
  //  - selection: Render whitespace characters only on selected text.
  //  - all
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "selection",
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Just tried this a while ago but it doesnt work, \n characters are still invisible

Answer (score 0):

Gremlin Tracker plugin for VS Code is great for finding invisible/weird characters in combination with the "Render Line Endings" plugin.

Gremlin Tracker: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins

Render Line Endings:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=medo64.render-crlf