# Showing red dot in gitlab editor in script copied from sql server management studio

Tags: git, encoding, gitlab, byte-order-mark

Red dots are showing in mostly in the starting but in some scripts showing in between the script in git lab editor. Owing to which we unable to deploy that script on production. Perhaps this is due to Unicode UTF-8 with BOM. I also saved it without signature (i.e. without BOM). Is there any way I can remove this dot from the script, because in long scripts it's difficult to find it and many scripts failed on account of this.

[image: Look at this picture, script has red dot.]

Show me the way how I can remove all the red dots at once.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your files with an editor than can highlight invisible characters (for example : VS Code has a [`"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code), Notepad++ has a menu entry "View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters" ...), and delete/replace the offending characters.

For a bulk edition, you can probably copy an instance of said character and "search&replace" for it.