# CSS error: at-rule or selector expected, { expected

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to run this code on Visual Studio Code and faced these errors:

at-rule or selector expected at Ln1 Col1, Ln7 Col 1, Ln50 Col1

{ expected at Ln2 Col1, Ln51 Col 1

I tried to run these on W3Schools and they ran just fine. How can I solve this issue? Here's the code, thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: white;
}

/* Text Display */

h1 {
    font-family: georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: black; /* Set text color to black */
    text-align: center;
}

#p1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: blue; /* Set text color to blue */
    text-align: center;  
}

.center {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: green; /* Set text color to green */
    text-align: center;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: blueviolet;
  }
  
  /* visited link */
  a:visited {
    color: gray;
  }
  
  /* mouse over link */
  a:hover {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  /* selected link */
  a:active {
    color: blue;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<h2 id="p1">Enjoy numerous movie reviews and recommendations here.</h2>
<h3 class="center">Featured movie of the week:</h3>
<p><b><a href="default.asp" target="_blank">Everything Everywhere All at Once</a></b></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: It sounds as though the system is looking at your code as though is is a CSS file rather than an HTML one.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code bottom right, change Language Mode to HTML from CSS.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But I've changed it and the errors are still there~~

Comment: @ValVal This is weird, have you tried reload the vs code or restarting it? The file extension name is .html ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your editor could have extra characters accidently placed somewhere

To see those you can refer this [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140595/show-whitespace-characters-in-visual-studio-code)

Otherwise copy your entire code a normal notepad in windows and paste it back to VS Code

Or you can use Notepad++ and see all characters and then delete them

Otherwise copy paste you code piece by piece one style at a time, you can narrow the issue