# How can I read a line's charactes from a file into a matrix?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with sequences like this:

```
>info
ATG
>info
GA
>info
TTAG
>info
ATTTT
```

I'd like to read this into a matrix:

```
matrix[0][0]=A , matrix[0][1]=T, matrix[0][2]=G
matrix[1][0]=G , matrix[1][1]=A
matrix[2][0]=T , matrix[2][1]=T, matrix[2][2]=A , matrix[2][3]=G
ETC...
```

Is this even possible in Python (pycharm), and if it is, how could I do that?

NEW code so far:

```
def read(sek):
listA=[]
regex = re.compile(r"[;>](?P<description>[^\n]*)\n(?P<sequence>[^;>]+)")
with open(sek, "r") as file:
     seq = regex.findall(file.read())
     for i, info in enumerate(seq):
        description, sequence = info
        for j < len(sequence):
            listA[i][j]= sequence
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
file.close()
return(listA)
read('sequence1.FASTA')
```

new error message: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

((original file has description lines, but I already have a solution for that so I didn't wrote it in this question))

Comment: It's definitely possible, just provide input and expected output (in a more cohesive sense, i.e. what happens at newlines) and provide what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I stuck at the matrix part..I can read into a string, but when i tried the matrix format [X][X]=something it wrote out an error message

Comment: Can you paste your code and error received?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with "Unexpected indent" in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python)

Comment: I didn't put in extra spaces, in the real code I only used the spaces the program automatically gave

Comment: also I don'tknow how to solve that the matrix count [i][X] should turn into [i+1][X] at every new row

Comment: You need to give an example of your actual input file.

Comment: actual file is Huge..but i corrected the example

Answer (score 0):

You can use list:

```
c = [];
c.append(list("ATG"))
c.append(list("GA"))
c.append(list("TTAG"))
print c[2][1]
```

You can create the matrix simply like this:

```
[list(x) for x in open('datafile').read().split("\n")]

>>>> [['A', 'T', 'G'], ['G', 'A'], ['T', 'T', 'A', 'G'], ['A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']]
```

In your code, the def block needs to be indented, just like while, for, if etc.

Comment: This is not helpful because the problem he's asking about has nothing to do with the actual parsing, he just has an indenterror. He can post a new question if his actual code has problems

Comment: ident thing is not the main problem

Answer (score 0):

The following would load your data from your text file:

```
def read(sek):
    listA = []
    with open(sek, "r") as file:
        for line1 in file:
            listA.append(list(next(file).strip()))
    return listA

print(read('sequence1.FASTA'))
```

This would display the following output:

```
[['A', 'T', 'G'], ['G', 'A'], ['T', 'T', 'A', 'G'], ['A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']]
```

Or if you prefer to use regular expressions, the following should also work:

```
def read(sek):
    with open(sek, "r") as file:
        return [list(line) for line in re.findall(r'^([ATGC]+)', file.read(), re.M)]
```

Note, if the file is huge, the first version avoids loading the whole file into memory at once, but could be slower.

Comment: This is not helpful because the problem he's asking about has nothing to do with the actual parsing, he just has an indenterror. He can post a new question if his actual code has problems

Comment: ident thing is not the main problem

Answer (score 0):

```
for j < len(sequence):
```

should be

```
while j < len(sequence):
```

To solve your syntax error.

Comment: unfrtunately it didn't :(