# Python: Indentation Error in simple code

Tags: python

I typed in the following code

```
def root():
    x = int(raw_input("Enter a number:\n"))
    y = int(raw_input("Enter the power which you want:\n"))
    return x^y
print "Hey, we are learning python!"
print "Let's learn about functions!"
print "The result is:", root()
```

I get the following error:

```
y = int(raw_input("Enter the power you want\n:"))
^
Indentation Error: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Maybe you are mixing tabs and spaces, you should use consistent indentation throughout the program (either only spaces or only tabs).

Comment: what is the line? you should reindent

Comment: `^` is xor, `**` is power.

Comment: You want `power` of a number but the function name is root? If you really want root, use `sqrt` function if you want square root or `**` and multiply by inverse

Comment: I want the power, sorry for the wrong naming of the function. I am using consistent indentation.(spaces) . I still am getting the error

Comment: straight copy & paste of your code works flawlessly for me...

Comment: Dunno what's the problem with my editor. I am using Notepad++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with "Unexpected indent" in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same indentation throughout your code.
If you start with 4 spaces, use 4 spaces everywhere.
If you start with tabs, continue with tabs etc.

For that reason, also be careful when copying code for a file with different indentations.

Some text editors  (i.e. Sublime) or IDEs can convert your whole file to the same indentation to avoid such errors.