# Python Error Calling Function Within Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I am a novice in python. I just extended the Hello World program:

```
import sys

def first(n):
    print "Hi Man"+" Huuuuuu"
    if len(sys.argv)>1: print sys.argv[1]

def second():
    print "Huuuuuuuuuuu"    
    first(7)

if __name__=='__main__':
    second()
```

I get the error:

```
File "first.py", line 11
    first(7)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I read [What to do with "Unexpected indent" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python), but I can't find the error.

I ran with python -t command:

```
python -t first.py
first.py: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
  File "first.py", line 12
    first(7)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I copy paste your code and get no errors. Are you sure the code you've shared is *exactly* what you're running?

Comment: Make sure your not using a mix of 4 spaces and tab.

Comment: There is almost certainly an indentation error in your code at line 12 (thus the IndentationError) . Calling a function within a function is not your issue. Fix the indentation.

Comment: @JonSurrell I just copied the code from my question and it worked ? It was not working before.

Comment: Seems that you are mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: @Alex.S yes, it is the exact issue. I got it now, the first(7) code I used tab....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with "Unexpected indent" in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python generally works by the indentation instead of curly braces block. In your case check the blank spaces in front of `first(7)`  statement are matching with the blank spaces with the first `print` statement.

Check if you have putted the tab character in one of the statement. generally we put the 4 blank spaces in front of the statement.