# Error in my file but in console it working

Tags: python

When i wrote it in run.py it have unexpected indent but when i wrote it in python console its working

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input


def hello(a, b):
    if b != 0:
        wynik = a/b
        return wynik
    else:
        wynik = "No result"
        return wynik



a = raw_input('Number A:')
b = raw_input("Number B:")

    if not a is None and not b is None:
    print(hello(float(a),float(b)))
    else:
    print("A or B must be filled")

raw_input()
```

This is log:

```
C:\Users\Student\PycharmProjects\untitled>run.py
  File "C:\Users\Student\PycharmProjects\untitled\run.py", line 17
    if not a is None and not b is None:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: the print statements should be indented.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python

Comment: Your `if` and `else` are over-indented. They should be on the same level as `a` and `b`

Comment: Remove the indents on the if and else statement.

Answer (score -1):

Invalid indentation, replace this:

```
    if not a is None and not b is None:
    print(hello(float(a),float(b)))
    else:
    print("A or B must be filled")
```

with this:

```
if not a is None and not b is None:
    print(hello(float(a),float(b)))
else:
    print("A or B must be filled")
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way

```py
rom pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input


def hello(a, b):
    if b != 0:
        wynik = a/b
        return wynik
    else:
        wynik = "No result"
        return wynik


a = raw_input('Number A:')
b = raw_input("Number B:")

if not a is None and not b is None:
    print(hello(float(a),float(b)))
else:
    print("A or B must be filled")

raw_input()
```