# "IndentationError: unexpected indent" When trying to copy and paste from text editor to terminal

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm brand new to Python, and I was wondering if someone could help me with something that seems to be a simple fix. However, I can't figure it out.

When I copy and paste the following code from my text editor to my terminal, I get an error saying:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

When I manually type in everything in Terminal, I don't get the error message and the program runs perfectly fine.

```
def decrypt(key, txtFile): \
    txtFile = encrypted.upper() \
    alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" \
    result = "" \
    for char in txtFile: \
        if char in alpha: \
            char_index = (alpha.find(char) - key) % len(alpha) \
            result = result + alpha[char_index] \
        else: \
            result = result + char \
    return result
```

'''

Comment: Why do you have all those backslashes?

Comment: Stop copy-pasting from file to terminal. If it's Python code in a file, run the file directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with "Unexpected indent" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python)

Comment: If you use [IPython](https://ipython.org/) instead of the regular Python console, you can paste entire code snippets with blank lines into a terminal without worrying about indentation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is all about indentation and whitespace in functions and classes.

If the above is the pasted code, you have the '\' on every line which may be causing the error. If this is still what is typed in and still not running - the white space indent from column 0 to 4 (1 tab space) may be another encoding so therefore causing an issue. Try copying the function and then removing the indentation then adding it back yourself, *after* you have removed the '\' from every line.

```
def decrypt(key, txtFile): 
    txtFile = encrypted.upper() 
    alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
    result = "" 
    for char in txtFile: 
        if char in alpha: 
            char_index = (alpha.find(char) - key) % len(alpha) 
            result = result + alpha[char_index] 
        else:
            result = result + char
    return result
```

Comment: Also try using nano or vim when writing in terminal or go to your IDE.

Comment: Thank you so much! You and the other guy helped me out a bunch. I'm not sure what I did wrong. I added the \ after trying a bunch of other stuff including rewriting it several times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your terminal is adding a backslash to the end of each line when it doesn't need it here. The backslash tells the interpreter to treat the two lines as a single line, and we don't want that here. Removing the \ worked for me.

```
def decrypt(key, txtFile):
    txtFile = encrypted.upper()
    alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    result = ""
    for char in txtFile:
        if char in alpha:
            char_index = (alpha.find(char) - key) % len(alpha)
            result = result + alpha[char_index]
        else:
            result = result + char
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I wasn't sure what \ did. I just noticed that some of the source code that my professor provided us had them for lines that were to be treated as one, but I wasn't sure exactly what to do.