# I made this program to find multiplicative table of number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me fix the loop (the IDE indicates "unexpected indent" on the first line) and Please suggest be other loops that can be used in the same place

```
while True:                              
num = int(input(""" Enter Number: """))      
temp = num                                           
numb = temp                                         
zar = 1                                             
print("Develped by Umar Mushtaq")                    
for _ in range(10):                                  
    print(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)             
    num += numb
    zar+= 1
print("Press Ctrl+C To Exit")
```

Comment: Can you attach your screenshot to the question and provide a little more clarity to your question? The error in your screenshot is about indentation due to the lines within your while loop not being indented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with "Unexpected indent" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016814/what-to-do-with-unexpected-indent-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code is indented by 1 tab, therefore causing and `IndentationError`. If you remove those, it will work, like here:

```py
while True:
  num = int(input(""" Enter Number: """))
  temp = num
  numb = temp
  zar = 1
  print("Develped by Umar Mushtaq")
  for _ in range(10):
    print(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)
    num += numb 
    zar += 1 
    print("Press Ctrl+C To Exit")
```

EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood the question OP was asking. I assume you are making a multiplication facts generator, in which case, here is another way of executing that, in a bit more of a pythony way:

```py
def generate_facts(number, max_number=10):
  return [f"{number} × {i} = {number * i}" for i in range(1, max_number + 1)]

while True:
  number = int(input(" Enter Number: ")) # Still a bit messy, but requires a lot of code to make better, so...
  print(*generate_facts(number),sep="\n")
```