# How to make Python runtime safe?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I've made an interface using Boost Python into my C++ code, calling the Python interpreter from my C++ code. I was curious to know if there's any API function or something that can make Python run-time safe. I mean is it possible to make the interpreter skip the faults and errors if any occurred in the code?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be better practice to simply catch any exceptions within the python code itself?

Comment: "Skipping" a fault or exception isn't an option because it may not be possible for the code to continue to run. Your best bet is to wrap the execution of all Python code in a `try/except` however there's not way to resume and continue at the point it occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Python has [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) functionality. You can wrap any code that has the potential to create an error in a try block:

```
 try:
     #do risky stuff
 except Exception as e:
     print "Exception", e, "received. Code will continue to execute"
     #do other stuff that needs to be done
```

You can replace `Exception` in that code with a specific type of exception that you're expecting, such as `ZeroDivisionError`, and then your code will only catch that type of error.

Comment: yep, here is a giant thread of all the available options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions

Comment: 'Module' has a specific meaning in Python.

Comment: I'm using Python interpreter in my C++ code and I want to do error handling in my c++ code! Handling errors in Python has a drawback that I don't want my c++ errors be handled by Python!

Comment: If you handle the errors in your C++ code, you won't be able to actually skip over them - you'll have to accept that whatever python function you were trying to run did not successfully executed. That said, the python boost documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html#exceptions) makes it look like any error that occurred in the python code should get propagated back to the C++ code, so you can check for it there.