# maya + python: Execute and continue upon errored operation

Tags: python, maya

Is there a way I can modify this script which tries to fillet two lines and results in an error during the operation, and continue on through the script? The try exception didn't seem to work.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.file(new=True, f=True)

# Create a circular fillet (by default) having radius 2.5 between the
# active curves:
a = cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5)] )
b = cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 10)] )
c = cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(0, 0, 10), (-5, 0, 10)] )

allShapes = [a,b,c]

# do the first fillet
filletA = cmds.filletCurve(a,b, r=1.5 )
if cmds.objExists(filletA):
    allShapes.append(filletA)

# do the second fillet  
filletB = cmds.filletCurve(b,c, r=1.5 )  
if cmds.objExists(filletB):
    allShapes.append(filletB) 

print 'ran'
print allShapes
```

the error

```
# Warning: No curve contact point specified. Using start of curve instead. # 
# Warning: No curve contact point specified. Using start of curve instead. # 
# Warning: filletCurve1 (Fillet Curve): failed to get normal. # 
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
#   File "C:\\Users\\Martini\\Desktop\\trash\\fillet_01.py", line 14, in <module>
#     filletA = cmds.filletCurve(a,b, r=1.5 )
# # RuntimeError: Command filletCurve failed. Open Script Editor for details.
```

Comment: updated above for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard python [try / except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions):

```
try: 
   #... do your stuff here...
except RuntimeError:
   #... continue here
```

limit your exception catching to ones you expect (in this case, RuntimeError is what Maya usually throws if a command fails) so you can get around Maya problems without hiding your errors.

Some general notes [here](http://tech-artists.org/downloads/GDC2011/GDC2011_SteveTheodore_EpicFail.pdf):

Comment: is there a better way to test the filleting on accidental lines that don't yield a true result?

Comment: Probably not one that's worth the time, no. Luckily In Python exception handling is cheap and no more confusing than an if statement. Google "EAFP python" for the theory

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it may be an error of maya update.

When you create an object or an attribute, sometimes maya won't refresh throught script.

As you can't use 'pause' to force refresh, you have to take the hard way and use : cmds.evalDeferred() command.