# try: / except: pass not continuing onto rest of script?

Tags: python, try-catch, except

This is part of my script:

```
try:    
    read2length = len(reads[1])
    x2 = data[read1length:read1length+read2length,0]
    y2 = data[read1length:read1length+read2length,1]
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.bar(x2,y2, align='center')
    fig.suptitle('Read 2 Camera Timeouts', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Cycle', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('#', fontsize=16)
    if read2length < 50:
        plt.xticks(x1, fontsize=14)
    fig.savefig(join((path),'Read 2 Camera Timeouts.jpg'))
except: pass 
try:
    read3length = len(reads[2])
    x3 = data[read1length+read2length:read1length+read2length+read3length,0]
    y3 = data[read1length+read2length:read1length+read2length+read3length,1]
    fig = plt.figure()    
    plt.bar(x3,y3, align='center')
    fig.suptitle('Read 3 Camera Timeouts', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Cycle', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('#', fontsize=16)
    if read3length < 50:
        plt.xticks(x1, fontsize=14)
    fig.savefig(join((path),'Read 3 Camera Timeouts.jpg'))
except: pass
```

I want the script to try the first one and the second one. whether they work or not i want the script to continue.

I keep getting read2length is not defined?

Whats going on?

Comment: Must read: [Why is `except: pass` a bad programming practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: You should **never** have `try...except...` with no Exception(s) chosen.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions for how you shall handle exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the expression `len(reads[1])` throws an exception (say, `IndexError`) then the name `read2length` is never assigned to.

This then leads to an exception if your next `try` block tries to use that name *anyway*.

You should really not use [pokemon exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice) (you *don't* want to catch them all, really). Keep your exception handling as close to the exception-throwing code as possible, and only handle *specific* exceptions.

For example, if you want to handle `reads[1]` throwing an index error, then *handle just that exception*:

```
try:
    read2length = len(reads[1])
except IndexError:
    # not enough elements here; assume 0
    read2length = 0
else:
    x2 = data[read1length:read1length+read2length,0]
    y2 = data[read1length:read1length+read2length,1]
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.bar(x2,y2, align='center')
    fig.suptitle('Read 2 Camera Timeouts', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Cycle', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('#', fontsize=16)
    if read2length < 50:
        plt.xticks(x1, fontsize=14)
    fig.savefig(join((path),'Read 2 Camera Timeouts.jpg'))
```

Now `read2length` is bound to an integer, always.

Answer (score 1):

If `read2length` is not defined, that the problem is on line 2, where len(reads[1]) throws an exception.

Print the `reads` out to see, why.

You shall also modify your `except: pass` and use:

```
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Do not forgot to import `sys before`

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
try:    
    read2length = len(reads[1])
    x2 = data[read1length:read1length+read2length,0]
    y2 = data[read1length:read1length+read2length,1]
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.bar(x2,y2, align='center')
    fig.suptitle('Read 2 Camera Timeouts', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Cycle', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('#', fontsize=16)
    if read2length < 50:
        plt.xticks(x1, fontsize=14)
    fig.savefig(join((path),'Read 2 Camera Timeouts.jpg'))
except: pass 
try:
    read3length = len(reads[2])
    x3 = data[read1length+read2length:read1length+read2length+read3length,0]
    y3 = data[read1length+read2length:read1length+read2length+read3length,1]
    fig = plt.figure()    
    plt.bar(x3,y3, align='center')
    fig.suptitle('Read 3 Camera Timeouts', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Cycle', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('#', fontsize=16)
    if read3length < 50:
        plt.xticks(x1, fontsize=14)
    fig.savefig(join((path),'Read 3 Camera Timeouts.jpg'))
except: pass
print 'foo'
```

results in

```
$ python q2.py
foo
```

on my system.  My guess is you're referencing read2length after the second try-catch block.

And pay attention to what everyone else is saying about "except: pass" being bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

You define read2length on your first try here:

```
try:    
    read2length = len(reads[1])
```

Which means if that try fails then read2length never gets defined. As a result when you try to use it in the second try:

```
try:
    read3length = len(reads[2])
    x3 = data[read1length+read2length:read1length+read2length+read3length,0]
    y3 = data[read1length+read2length:read1length+read2length+read3length,1]
```

it will always fail due to the udnefined variable.

Change it by making the except on the first try to:

```
except:
    read2length = 0
```

Edit: Martijn beat me too it, but his answer is better as you shouldn't have generic excepts (or use pass).