# Ignore scipy NoConvergence

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using scipy to find the root(s) of a vector function and I want to have it ignore non-convergence.  Basically, I set the function tolerance and maxiter, but if it doesn't converge within those constraints I don't really care.  I'm using `scipy.optimize.newton_krylov` and setting the arguments `maxiter` and `f_tol`.  I just don't want non-convergence to raise an exception.

EDIT: I was a little unclear.  I want to get the solution from the optimizer even if it doesn't "converge."  I *can* handle this with a `try/except`, but this is slow.  It would require re-running the optimizer, which is computationally expensive.  I know (for my problem) a good solution will be found after `maxiter` iterations, but a good enough solution can often be found if `|F| < f_tol`, which can cut down on the total number of iterations by a lot and save lots of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions

Comment: What *should* happen, if not an exception? My guess is that you'll want to catch the exception and do whatever constitutes "ignoring it" for your particular situation.

Comment: @anon : It's not a case of the try/except handling.  To handle the exception I'd have to re-run the optimizer, which is computationally expensive.

Answer (score 4):

The NoConvergence exception that is thrown on non-convergence contains the latest iteration as its argument. So you can do

```
try:
    x = newton_krylov(F, x0)
    converged = True
except NoConvergence as e:
    x = e.args[0]
    converged = False
```

Comment: For those who want to use the above code, `NoConvergence` is in `scipy.optimize.nonlin`.