# running python code despite KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

I get a KeyError for one of the entries in the dataframe, but I would like the code to continue with the other entries which seem to have not problem. I have been reading about the except() option but don't know how to use it. Can you help

Comment: You have to show your code that raise the `KeyError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic form of exception handling in python uses [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions):

```
try:
    #code which gives key error (replace pass with your code)
    pass

except KeyError:
    #do some exception handling here (or just pass)
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just the fix I was looking for. I put the section of code that was giving the KeyError under try and passed if there was an exception

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a dataframe `df`, this is how you handle the `KeyError` exception:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame()

try:
    print df[0]
except KeyError as exc:
    print "Caught KeyError: {}".format(exc)
```

**Output**

```
Caught KeyError: 0
```

The same also works on dictionaries. You can see here that the exception is bound to `exc` in the `except` clause and can be accessed within the exception handler. In Python 3, `exc` is not accessible outside of the `except` clause; in Python 2 it is accessible (but you should follow the Python 3 way).