# Python Pandas : Select data and ignoring KeyErrors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

Note: my question isn't [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517943/running-python-code-despite-keyerror), but something a little more subtle.

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = 
    A     B    C
0   3     3    1
1   2     1    9
```

`df[["A", "B", "D"]]` will raise a `KeyError`.

Is there a python pandas way to let `df[["A", "B", "D"]] == df[["A", "B"]]`? (Ie: just select the columns that exist.)

One solution might be

```
good_columns = list(set(df.columns).intersection(["A", "B", "D"]))
mydf = df[good_columns]
```

But this has two problems:

- It's clunky and inelegant.
- The ordering of `mydf.columns` could be `["A", "B"]` or `["B", "A"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), this will just ignore any extra keys:

```
df.filter(["A","B","D"])
    A     B  
0   3     3   
1   2     1
```

Comment: Thank you. I wish the pandas documentation had usage examples for each function, just like scikit-learn.

Comment: why don't you consider submitting some yourself, documentation is a great way to get started with contributing to open-source projects

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional list comprehension:

```
target_cols = ['A', 'B', 'D']
>>> df[[c for c in target_cols if c in df]]
   A  B
0  3  3
1  2  1
```

Comment: Looks like that's an `O(n)` check to see if `c in df`. I'll stick with @maxymoo's answer. Thanks!