# Python ignore all errors and continue running

Tags: python

Is there any way to run .py script and if it occurs an error, to just restart it or continue. Right now if there's an error the script will stop running.

Comment: that's why `try` `except` blocks present in python.

Comment: @opengl, if it did not work you did not use it correctly. Catch any possible exceptions and restart the script

Comment: You may also find [`fuckit`](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) helpful

Comment: I would also recommend [logging.exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.exception) , so you can figure out what the bleep happened later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch errors and ignore them (if it makes sense). eg if the call `foo.bar()` could cause an error use

```
try:
    foo.bar()
except: #catch everything, should generally be avoided.
    #what should happen when an error occurs
```

If you only want to ignore a certain type of error use (recommended) (python 2)

```
try:
    foo.bar()
except <ERROR TO IGNORE>, e:
    #what should happen when an error occurs
```

or (python 3)

```
try:
    foo.bar()
except <ERROR TO IGNORE> as e:
    #what should happen when an error occurs
```

See the [Python documentation on handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more information.

Comment: Note that the Python documentation warns: "The last except clause may omit the exception name(s), to serve as a wildcard. Use this with extreme caution, since it is easy to mask a real programming error in this way!"

Comment: @tsroten, true, added in comments to that effect

Comment: @tsroten, not sure what happened to your edit, added in as well

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575187/3140992 for quickly ignoring multiple commands, thanks to @jonrsharpe