# Python Job Not Ending

Tags: python, spyder

I've had a strange occurance. I stopped a python script manually, but its still running. It shows it as stopped in my IDE (Spyder) but I can see it's still running in task manager.  I also know it still processing because its still outputting files to a directory.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it on a go forward?

[image: task]

Comment: close the process and run your code again. does it happens again?

Comment: Tell me more about how you wrote your job

Comment: @gerosalesc I think i found an incorrectly written if / pass / else.  Could that have caused it?  Even so, if you stop it manually shouldn't that stop it regardless of what's going on in the script?

Comment: @Dot_Py i think its inconsistant based upon when i stop it.  In particular, the record i stop it on which could be a factor of the error / exception handling i mentioned in my comment to gerosalesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, i needed to add Exception to my except statement.  Thanks gerosalesc and Dot_Py for your help.

[Try/Except in Python: How do you properly ignore Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions)