# Is there any way to catch the specific variable name when failed to executing python eval in enviroment?

Tags: python

```
def func(param):
    #do something
```

Code:

```
    enviroment = {'func':func}
    eval('func(a)', enviroment, enviroment)
```

I originally want to use **getattr** in enviroment, but it seems not helpful

error occured when searching param a in environment,  is there any way to catch the error? Then I can append the a in the environment and executing again.

any answer would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is the question on how to catch an error? Then this might help: [Try/Except in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions)

Comment: I mean when failed to search the param a in the environment, how to know the error is "cannot find the param a"

Comment: Do you mean test whether or not an argument is provided for a function?

Answer (score 1):

The following code,

```
def func(param):
    print param

enviroment = {'func':func}
try:
    eval('func(a)', enviroment, enviroment)
except NameError as err:
    name = str(err).split("'")[1]
    enviroment[name] = "something"
print enviroment['a']
```

outputs:

`'something'`

When executing the eval statement, a NameError is returned:

`NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

And so we can catch that error and respond to it by extracting the `'a'`.

Comment: This answer is lacking in explanation – could you provide explanation to your code? (edit: Also I think we need to put off with the answers until OP clarifies his question.)

Comment: the output result is not the string of 'something' but the string of ''name 'a' is not defined

Comment: If I copy-paste from the StackOverflow code block it works for Python 2 and 3:

Comment: Python 2: https://repl.it/E6mz/0
Python 3: https://repl.it/E6nD/0

I didn't mean to press the Enter key in the last comment.

Comment: Make sure you include `.split("'")[1]` after `str(err)`. Without it, I too get `name 'a' is not defined`.

Comment: oh,I wrongly regard the exception err as the name. got it, thank you very much@Matthew Kleinsmith