# how to NOT read_csv if csv is empty

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python 2.7 and Pandas

I have to parse through my directory and plot a bunch of CSVs. If the CSV is empty, the script breaks and produces the error message:

```
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

If I have my file paths stored in

```
file_paths=[]
```

how do I read through each one and only plot the non empty CSVs? If I have an empty dataframe defined as df=[] I attempt the following code

```
for i in range(0,len(file_paths)):
   if pd.read_csv(file_paths[i] == ""):
      print "empty"
   else df.append(pd.read_csv(file_paths[i],header=None))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the in built `try` and `except` syntax to skip over files that return you an error, as follows:

Described here: [Try/Except in Python: How do you properly ignore Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions)

```
for i in range(0,len(file_paths)):
   try:
       pd.read_csv(file_paths[i])
       ### Do Some Stuff
   except:
       continue
       # or pass
```

This will attempt to read each file, and if unsuccessful continue to the next file.

Comment: You are welcome: I am glad this solved your problem. In the interests of the dissemination of proper standards: @Boud is right though - his answer is less general.

Comment: I think such a broad except is not a best practice, the answer by @Boud is more appropriate.

Answer (score 40):

I would just catch the appropriate exception, as a catch all is not recommended in python:

```
import pandas.io.common

for i in range(0,len(file_paths)):
   try:
      pd.read_csv(file_paths[i])
   except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError:
      print file_paths[i], " is empty"
```

Comment: This seems to have changed since this solution was posted. 
Now need to use pandas.errors instead of pandas.io.common

Answer (score 30):

Note, as of pandas 0.22.0 (that I can be sure of) , the exception raised for empty csv is [`pandas.errors.EmptyDataError`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.errors.EmptyDataError.html). And if you're importing pandas like `import pandas as pd`, then use `pd` instead of `pandas`.

If your csv filenames are in an array `manyfiles`, then

```
import pandas as pd
for filename in manyfiles:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        print('Note: filename.csv was empty. Skipping.')
        continue # will skip the rest of the block and move to next file

    # operations on df
```

I'm not sure if `pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError` is still valid or not. Can't find it in reference docs. And I also would advise against the catch-all `except:` as you won't be able to know if it's something else causing the issue.

Comment: Pandas version 1.0 moved error handling to `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError`.