# In Pandas- how to check of dataframe is empty after every manipulation?

Tags: python, pandas

In doing a lot of manipulations on dataframe and in one of them it can return empty (which an except able result).

the thing is if turns empty it crashes on the other line, like in the following code:

```
NumOfActiveDays = local_input_list.groupby(['DeviceSidID'])['timestamp'].nunique().reset_index().rename(columns={'timestamp': 'NumOfDays'})
NumOfActiveDays = NumOfActiveDays[NumOfActiveDays.NumOfDays >= float(extdf.dict[entity]['days_thresh'])]
local_input_list = local_input_list[local_input_list.DeviceSidID.isin(NumOfActiveDays.loc[:, 'DeviceSidID'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

if NumOfActiveDays will become empty it will crash the third line...
is there a better why to check if data manipulation ends up empty instead of after every line to do `if df.empty()`?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a try, except statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions