# ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am following a this tutorial to write a Naive Bayes Classifier:
http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/

I keep getting this error:

```
dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Here is the part of my code where the error occurs:

```
def loadDatasetNB(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename, "rt"))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
```

And here is how the file is called:

```
def NB_Analysis():
    filename = 'fvectors.csv'
    splitRatio = 0.67
    dataset = loadDatasetNB(filename)
    trainingSet, testSet = splitDatasetNB(dataset, splitRatio)
    print('Split {0} rows into train={1} and test={2} rows').format(len(dataset), len(trainingSet), len(testSet))
    # prepare model
    summaries = summarizeByClassNB(trainingSet)
    # test model
    predictions = getPredictionsNB(summaries, testSet)
    accuracy = getAccuracyNB(testSet, predictionsNB)
    print('Accuracy: {0}%').format(accuracy)

NB_Analysis()
```

[My file fvectors.csv looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIEYG.png)

What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Try to skip a header, an empty header in the first column is causing the issue.

```
>>> float(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If you want to skip the header you can achieve it with:

```
def loadDatasetNB(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename, "rt"))
    next(reader, None)  # <<- skip the headers
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
```

(2) Or you can just ignore the exception:

```
try:
    float(element)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

If you decide to go with option (2), make sure that you skip only first row or only rows that contain text and you know it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image of your data, python cannot convert the last column of your data with the values `square` and `circle`.  Also, you have a header in your data that you need to skip.

Try using this code:

```
def loadDatasetNB(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        reader= csv.reader(fp)
        # skip the header line
        header = next(reader)
        # save the features and the labels as different lists
        data_features = []
        data_labels = []
        for row in reader:
            # convert everything except the label to a float
            data_features.append([float(x) for x in row[:-1]])
            # save the labels separately
            data_labels.append(row[-1])
    return data_features, data_labels
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an empty line.

```
>> float('')
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

You can check the value before casting it:

```
dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i] if x != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading strings into the `float` constructor here, which unless are under specific conditions, raises an error:

```
dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
```

Instead of using a list comprehension, perhaps it would be better to use a for loop so you can more easily handle this case:

```
data = []
for x in dataset[i]:
    try:
        value = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        value = x
    data.append(value)
dataset[i] = data
```

See more about catching exceptions here:

[Try/Except in Python: How do you properly ignore Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions)