# python continue with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

I have a loop code in python like this:

```
 for index, row in maproad.iterrows():
    road = wkb.loads(row['THE_GEOM'], hex=True)
    buffered_road = Polygon(road.buffer(0.00015,cap_style=2,resolution=2))
    print(row['OBJECTNAME'])
    c.write({
    'geometry': mapping(Polygon(buffered_road.exterior)),
    'properties': {'name': row['OBJECTNAME']}
     }) 

     if road:
     road = wkb.loads(row['THE_GEOM'], hex=False)
     continue
```

I want to continue the loop but it throws THE_GEOM parsing error.
So i got stuck and i am really noob to python.
Thankyou

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions

Comment: A`continue` a the last command in the loop does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    <code that might give error>
except Whatever_Error:
    continue
```