# Handling exception in Python

Tags: python

I have written Python code which does some calculation. During this it converts `string` to `float`. However sometimes numeric string value may be empty that time its giving me `valueError`. I tried to keep that in try catch block however its going to another exception block as shown below.

```
try:
   float(some value)
except Exception as ValueError:
   print(error message)

except Exception as oserror:
   print(mesage)
```

Its going to os error block instead of `ValueError` block

Comment: And what does the oserror say?

Comment: Syntax:   `except  WhatToCatch:` or `except  WhatToCatch as HowToNameItForReference:` - read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html - WhatToCatch: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try/Except in Python: How do you properly ignore Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you capture exceptions.

```
try:
    float(some value)
except ValueError as e:
    print("here's the message", e.args)
except OSError as e:
    print("here's a different message")
```

(Note, though, there's no instance when calling `float` would raise an OSError.)

Comment: This means it never goes to ValueError Block at all !

Comment: What value are you using?