# How to catch concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to catch exception thrown inside a `run_until_complete` but whatever I try, I can't seems to catch them properly.

Here's my latest attempt (note, I'm using Pypputeer, a fork of Puppeteer in Python, that uses asyncio):

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer.launcher import launch

async def test(instance):
    page = await instance.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://www.google.com', {'waitUntil': 'load', 'timeout': 1})
    await page.pdf({'path': 'example.pdf'})


async def test2():
    instance = launch(headless=True)
    try:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(test(instance))
        print(task)
        await task
    except:
        print("Caught!")

    instance.close()


def __main__():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(test2())
    except:
        print("ERROR")
    return 'ok'
```

The issue I'm having with this code, is two fold:

1. if I do `asyncio.get_event_loop` instead, I get the following error:

> There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
> 2. If I change the timeout to a decent value, I get the following error (at     `loop.run_until_complete(test2())`):
> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
> 3. If I set the timeout to 1 (to force the error), I get the exception indicated below, shown in the console, and the text "ERROR" is shown. (but not caught).

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Exception in callback NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation.<locals>.watchdog_cb(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at /home/user/www/project/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/navigator_watcher.py:49
handle: <Handle NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation.<locals>.watchdog_cb(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at /home/user/www/project/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/navigator_watcher.py:49>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/home/user/www/project/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/navigator_watcher.py", line 52, in watchdog_cb
    self._timeout)
  File "/home/user/www/project/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/navigator_watcher.py", line 40, in _raise_error
    raise error
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 1 ms exceeded
```

So, TLDR, how can I catch exceptions thrown inside a `run_until_complete` call of asyncio?

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch this error because it doesn't happen somewhere before event loop finished it's work:

```
loop.run_until_complete(test2())
print('TEST !!!')  # You will see this line, because there was no exception before
```

But if you look at whole traceback you will see:

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
```

It means exception happens inside one of the functions Pypputeer registered using [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/atexit.html) handler. You should search how to catch exception there, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

> If an exception is raised during execution of the exit handlers, a
>   traceback is printed (unless SystemExit is raised) and the exception
>   information is saved. After all exit handlers have had a chance to run
>   the last exception to be raised is re-raised.

---

Not related, but [never do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730778/1113207) such thing.

```
except:
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. On the side note, the `except` was just to speed things up here. Since it's said "After all exit handlers have had a chance to run the last exception to be raised is re-raised.", wouldn't it be possible to catch it?

Comment: @CyrilN.I googled a bit before posting answer and couldn't find a solution. But I can't say I'm sure there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        try:
            print("Try and wait for socket receive ...")
            payload = bson.loads(await asyncio.wait_for(socket.recv(), timeout=5.0))
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout Error")
            await socket.close()
            return None
```