# FORBIDDEN (status code: 403) Can't send messages to this user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command that will send a DM to the entire server, but I am getting the following error:

```
Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403) Can't send messages to this user
```

What might be causing this?

Here is my current code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def massdm(ctx, words*):
    output = " "
    for word in words:
        output += word
        output += "" 
    server = ctx.message.server
    for member in server.members:
        await bot.send_message(member, output)
```

Comment: The user might have blocked your bot or disabled the server’s DMs, just catch the error, drop it and move on.

Comment: How would I do that? Snake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/730778

Answer (score 1):

The user might have blocked your bot or disabled DMs for your server, either way, you won’t be able to salvage the situation, so simply dropping the exception will do.

```
try:
  /* send message */
except Exception: 
  pass
```

Comment: You should catch `discord.Forbidden` instead of the more general (and less specific) `Exception`