# Why is this usage of "except" a syntax error in Python 3?

Tags: python, syntax, except

I am trying to write a simple program which will turn lights on and off based on the time of day, in Python 3.

I keep on getting a syntax error when try and use `except KeyboardInterrupt:` in a `while` loop. This is the error:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As I have doubled checked the syntax with online documentation I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong and I guess I am missing some piece of understanding here.

Here is the full code for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  

import time
import datetime

TimeStart = datetime.time(17, 0, 0)
TimeEnd = datetime.time(18, 30, 0)

def onoff():
    while True:
        if TimeEnd > datetime.datetime.now().time() and TimeStart < datetime.datetime.now().time():
            print("Pin 18  High")
        else:
            print("Pin 18  Low")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
            print("Error..... Quiting.....")
            raise
            sys.exit()

time.sleep(30)   
onoff()
```

Comment: An `except` must follow a `try` block

Comment: `except` belongs with `try`, not `if`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: Look here, do a bit of research please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions

Comment: `except` is not something you can just add to other statements. It's a syntax error because `except` can only be used when there is a `try:` block *first* to connect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `except` statement outside of a `try: ... except: ...` code block.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

So you would rephrase your code as

```
while True:
    try:
        if TimeEnd > datetime.datetime.now().time() and TimeStart < datetime.datetime.now().time() :
            print ("Pin 18  High")
        else:
            print ("Pin 18  Low")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
        print("Error..... Quiting.....")
        raise
        sys.exit()
```

which I haven't tried but essentially

- wraps the if statement with a `try` clause, and
- any `KeyboardInterrupt` would be captured by the `except` statement.