# In python, how to ignore an exception and process odd code?

Tags: python, exception

sample:

```
with suppress(Exception)
    os.remove('test1.log')
    os.remove('test2.log')

try:
    os.remove('test1.log')
    os.remove('test2.log')
except:
    pass
```

test2.log will not be deleted if test1.log isn't exist because *FileNotFoundError*. So how to process odd code after an exception happened, or how to prevent an exception been throw?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

In a `try-except` if an exception is triggered, it will go the the `except` part than continue from there. So if you want to make sure both `remove` are attempted, do this:

```
try:
    os.remove('test1.log')
except:
    pass

try:
    os.remove('test2.log')
except:
    pass
```

Alternatively, you can try checking if the file exists, before deleting it:

```
if os.path.exists('test1.log'):
   os.remove('test1.log')
if os.path.exists('test2.log'):
   os.remove('test2.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the duplicate explains, you can't just suppress the exceptions.

You probably want something like this:

```py
files = ["test1.log", "test2.log"]
for file in files:
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

tituszban already gave a valid solution.
You could also simply put your statements into a for-loop, which is shorter syntax since you don't have to repeat your try-catch blocks (especially useful when trying to delete more than 2 items).

```
lst = ["test1.log","test2.log"]
for element in lst:
    try:
        os.remove(element)
    except:
        pass
```