# shorting console output via csv

Tags: python, file, csv, output

I am able to get the content from an csv file:

```
import csv

with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/tst/test.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[0])
```

that get my first (0) line. So far so good, but the output is now:

1. a
2. b
3. c

So how do i get those a, b and c? 
I tried to add them to a list, that wont work at all

Example:
We have a Path,Name -- under the path are 3 file paths written.
I can acess those paths with: the code above.
So i am getting three paths 
among themselves
How to get the first path?

[image]
I need the testpath1 only, but I am getting everypath with my code

Comment: Hi, can you explain better what output you expect? you can access the strings from `line[0]` the same way you access it to print them.

Comment: Hey @LittleDuck19, could you also attach sample from the file you are parsing?

Comment: Sure look at the Edit @mrVoid

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Pandas](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/) to read the csv and explore with it.

Comment: Nah not really. Thanks I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate the results in a list like this:

```
my_list = []
for line in csv_reader:
    my_list.append(line[0])
```

And then use it like this:

```
for item in my_list:
    do_something(item)
```

However, you can already do that from the start and skip the extra list:

```
for line in csv_reader:
    do_something(line[0])
```

Edit:

If you need only the first item you can use `next` to grab the first line (like you are already using `next` to skip over the header probably):

```
next(csv_reader) # here you are pulling the first line without using it

line = next(csv_reader)
print(line) # this gives you the second line: a

line2 = next(csv_reader)
print(line2) # b
print(next(csv_reader)) # c
next(csv_reader) # if you call it after the file is finished you'll get a StopIteration exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: Same problem: I am getting more output. So my list contain a,b,c but how to access only the a?

Comment: You access the a the first run of the loop. Do you only want to access the a and not the b and c?

Comment: See my edit in the question, should be clear now :)

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem, how to get rid of that error? I tried sth like: row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_reader) for the number of rows in csv file. I have to get this into a for loop right?

Comment: You can ignore the error using a try: ... except: pass block, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/730764/154762

Comment: If you need the number of rows you can probably use `len(csv_reader)` and then `csv_file.seek(0)` to reset it back to the start.

Comment: Hey, I hope u can finally help me bc I am stupid. I have a very long code which using the next(csv_reader) part. After this code, I need the next row, so If all this finshed, I need to restart the whole code, BUT add next(csv_reader) at the top, you know what I mean?