# How to ignore exceptions and proceed with whole blocks (multiple lines) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

How can I ignore all exceptions for a given **block** of code such that an exception is not only ignored, but also doesn't prevent the next line from being executed?

For example, consider the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def one():
    raise Exception
    print( 'one' )
def two():
    print( 'two' )

try:
    one()
    two()
except:
    pass
```

I would like the above code to print `two` but it actually prints nothing because the "ignored" exception still prevents the execution of `two()`.

Is it possible to *actually* ignore exceptions in blocks of python code?

EDIT: The application for this is for a `close()` function that does some cleanup when my app is exiting. It needs to happen as fast as possible and will consist of *many* commands (not just two as the example I used, but it could be dozens of unrelated actions). And if one line fails, it shouldn't stop the next from trying. Please tell me there's a better option than "just use more than one `try` block"..

Comment: If you have multiple statements belonging together (especially in a try block), then those statements are usually reliant on each other. So when one fails, you don’t want to execute the next one. Exceptions are _supposed_ to cancel the execution.

Comment: "Exceptions are supposed to cancel the executions" -- Sure, And choosing to ignore an exception is *supposed* to ignore exceptions.

Comment: _Catching_ an exception isn’t ignoring an exception though.

Comment: I guess most of the answers to this question are invalid then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [`fuckit`](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) python module.

Here is the code modified from your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fuckit

def one():
    raise Exception
    print( 'one' )
def two():
    print( 'two' )

@fuckit
def helper():
    one()
    two()

helper()
```

And an example execution:

```
user@disp3221:~$ sudo python3 -m pip install fuckit
Collecting fuckit
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/f4/0952081f9e52866f4a520e2d92d27ddf34f278d37204104e4be869c6911d/fuckit-4.8.1.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: fuckit
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for fuckit ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/a9/24/e6/a3e32536d1b2975c23ac9f6f1bdbc591d7b968e5e0ce6b4a4f
Successfully built fuckit
Installing collected packages: fuckit
Successfully installed fuckit-4.8.1
user@disp3221:~$ 

user@disp3221:~$ ./test.py 
two
user@disp3221:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `two` function when raised exception, you could add it in the `finally` block:

```
def one():
    raise Exception
    print( 'one' )
def two():
    print( 'two' )

try:
    one()
except:
    pass
finally:
    two()
```