# how to handle exception without exiting from function?

Tags: python

```
def clear_environment():
    delete_deploy_job() # could throw an exception
    delete_filler_job() # could throw an exception
    delete_project() # could throw an exception
    delete_pods() # could throw an exception
```

I need all these functions to execute, even if one of them throws an exception
Which is the best approach for this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look here https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/

Comment: Either put a `try...except` around each function call, or (better) put a `try...except` in each function... better because inside from the function you can provide a more informative log message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly ignore exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try them in a loop:

```py
def clear_environment():
    funcs = [delete_deploy_job, delete_filler_job, delete_project, delete_pods]
    for f in funcs:
        try:
            f()
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: I'd add something like `log.exception('Cleanup %s failed', f.__name__)` to the `except`.