# Stop displaying this error and print instead just "error"

Tags: python

how to stop displaying this error and print instead just "error":

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='domain.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f21ceed4690>: 
   Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Comment: Put a `try/except` around the line of code that throws this error.

Comment: Can you show the code? You probably need to capture exceptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly ignore exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions)