# Bypass error and continue code

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

This was a simple problem I was having earlier. Essentially, [solutions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574730/python-how-to-ignore-an-exception-and-proceed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-to-properly-ignore-exceptions?lq=1) to "ignoring" an exception really don't. Even if they don't crash python anymore, they still stop whatever code was in the initial try clause.

```
try:
    assert False
    print "hello"
except AssertionError:
    pass
```

This code will *not* print "hello", but rather skip over it, going to the pass. My question is, is there an easy way to truly ignore this in Python 2.7? I read about some things going on in 3.4 to make this easier, but I'd rather stay with python 2.7.

Comment: It looks like you have some design problem in your program. Can you please describe why do you need such exception ignoring?

Comment: This is a good argument for having *only the code you think could fail* in the `try` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can, and I don't think you should.

> Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.
>
> *Zen of Python*

It means that it's your duty as a programmer to think where and why exceptions might arise. You should (have to, actually) avoid the temptation to put a long block of code in a `try` statement and then think about exceptions. The correct thought flow is:

1. Write `assert False`
2. Notice that it *might* raise an AssertionError
3. Put `assert False` in a `try...except...` block
4. Write `print 'Hello'`
5. Notice that this line will not cause any errors (famous last words, by the way)
6. Profit

So your code should look like this (other answers are pretty nice, too):

```
try:
    assert False
except AssertionError:
    pass
print 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

```
try:
    assert False
    print "Hello"
except AssertionError:
    pass
finally:
    print "This prints no matter what"

This prints no matter what
```

If you want to execute a code block in the case the error does not occur you can use the `try except else` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Move what you want to happen if the error *doesn't* occur to an `else` block:

```
try:
    assert False
except AssertionError:
    print "error"
else:
    print "no error"
```