# How to get past errors in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, exception

The following code is being used to copy Excel documents to a new directory but I am getting some different errors which prevent the script from completing.

```
import os
from shutil import copy
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("T:/DIR"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xls") or file.endswith('xlsx'):
            copy(os.path.join(root, file),"C:/DIR")
```

The errors range from permission errors, to file not found errors. I need to make the script pass these and continue. There are tutorials on exception handling but I don't know how to actually use them with my code. For example, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574730/python-how-to-ignore-an-exception-and-proceed) says to use:

```
except:
    pass
```

but where exactly am I supposed to put this in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from shutil import copy
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("T:/DIR"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xls") or file.endswith('xlsx'):
            try:
                # attempt condition that may cause error
                copy(os.path.join(root, file),"C:/DIR")
            except:
                # handle exception here.
                pass
```

It is usually a good idea to handle the type of exception with each
use of `except:`. You could also log the errors in the `except:` section.

Read the Python tutorial on [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for better understanding.