# How to ignore an SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web

How do I keep my script running after encountering this error?

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.funcate.org.br', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /pt/portal-de-compras?file=../../../index.php%250A
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:718)'),))

Comment: [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53123565/edit) your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help people help you. That said, you might just need a simple [`try`/`except`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575711/3551604).

Comment: ...well, `try`/`except` if you don't want the untrustable content. If you want to retrieve the content anyhow, that calls for a different solution.

Comment: ...also, are you really sure you want to *ignore* the error, as opposed to (f/e) embedding the certificate in your software so you can validate it, and thus avoiding the error without completely giving up the security that SSL is supposed to offer you?

Answer (score 6):

You can switch off SSL certificate verification by passing `verify=False` as an extra argument to the `requests.get()` function:

```
response = requests.get('https://foobar.com.br/', verify=False)
```

Be advised that this will make you susceptible to all sorts of [man in the middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). SSL certificates are used for a reason :-) Although I realize that you are not necessarily in a position to enforce this.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @dpr You're right of course. I gave in to the temptation of answering in style with the question. I shall edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: When answering in style of the question you should have omitted the formatting 