# certificate verify failed in intercepting traffic w/ Fiddler Classic

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, fiddler

I got a simple Python script that reads a playlist from google music using the [YTMusic](https://github.com/sigma67/ytmusicapi) package/library:

```
from ytmusicapi import YTMusic
ytmusic = YTMusic('headers_auth.json')
blah = ytmusic.get_playlist('blah')
```

It works fine but when I use Fiddler Classic on my Win 10 machine & I decrypt SSL traffic I get:

> Exception has occurred: SSLError
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='music.youtube.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /youtubei/v1/browse?alt=json&key=blah (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

Maybe I can tell Python to ignore SSL errors at the global level (as I don't control the http requests in the library)?  I see [there's a `verify` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123685/185123) one can pass as `false` but I don't control that code, the library does.

What else can I do?

(I'm able to use chrome & Fiddler classic is able to intercept that traffic)

Comment: Check the dependencies of the python packe `YTMusic` belongs to. If you know the used http client used you can check how to add Fiddler certificate or disable TLS certificate checking.

Comment: [it appears](https://github.com/sigma67/ytmusicapi/blob/20b4631c31b65d5d40caf89b5db5fd661e82a979/ytmusicapi/ytmusic.py#L1) to be using [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) @Robert