# How to ignore "KeyError" in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, keyerror

I am trying to analyze stocks within python using the api "yfinance." I get the program to run just fine most of the time. However, when it is unable to 'find' one of the fields, it throughs up an error (KeyError). Here is a snippet of my code.

```py
import yfinance as yf
stock = yf.Ticker(stock)
pegRatio = stock.info['pegRatio']
print(pegRatio)
if pegRatio > 1:
    print("The PEG Ratio for "+name+" is high, indicating that it may be overvalued (based on projected earnings growth).")
if pegRatio == 1:
    print("The PEG Ratio for "+name+" is 1, indicating that it is close to fair value.")
if pegRatio < 1:
    print("The PEG Ratio for "+name+" is low, indicating that it may be undervalued (based on projected earnings growth).")
```

This was the error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        line 29, in 
    industry = stock.info['industry']
KeyError: 'industry'

My main question is how do I get the code to basically ignore the error and run the rest of the code?

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: that's called "error handling" and you can find plenty of info about that online.

Comment: If you want to post code here do 
\`\`\` 
all lines of your code here 
\`\`\`

Answer (score 1):

#### Error Handling in Python

Like [Nicolas commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978929/keyerror-in-yfinance-python#comment109620162_61978929) already, you will find many tutorials, blog posts and videos in the web. Also some basic Python books that cover "Error Handling".

The control-structure in Python consists of at least 2 keywords `try` and `except`, often named [try-except block](https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/). There are also 2 optional keywords `else` and `finally`.

#### How to wrap your failing statements

```py
import yfinance as yf

try: # st art watching for errors
  stock = yf.Ticker(stock)  # the API call may also fail, e.g. no connection
  pegRatio = stock.info['pegRatio']  # here your actual exception was thrown
except KeyError:  # catch unspecific or specific errors/exceptions
  # handling this error type begins here: print and return
  print "Error: Could not find PEG Ratio in Yahoo! Finance response!"
  return 

# the happy path continues here: with pegRatio
print(pegRatio)
if pegRatio > 1:
    print("The PEG Ratio for "+name+" is high, indicating that it may be overvalued (based on projected earnings growth).")
if pegRatio == 1:
    print("The PEG Ratio for "+name+" is 1, indicating that it is close to fair value.")
if pegRatio < 1:
    print("The PEG Ratio for "+name+" is low, indicating that it may be undervalued (based on projected earnings growth).")
```

Comment: Raymond Hettinger suggests that it's more idiomatic to ignore ("suppress") expected errors and exceptions when it would otherwise just make the code more verbose and less readable. Use `contextlib.suppress` for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566001/202834