# Pyinstaller loading splash screen

Tags: python, pyinstaller, splash-screen

Pyinstaller recently added a splash screen option (yay!) but the splash stays open the entire time the exe is running. I need it because my file opens very slowly and I want to warn the user not to close the window. Is there a way I can get the splash screen to close when the gui opens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from pyinstaller docs:

```
import pyi_splash

# Update the text on the splash screen
pyi_splash.update_text("PyInstaller is a great software!")
pyi_splash.update_text("Second time's a charm!")

# Close the splash screen. It does not matter when the call
# to this function is made, the splash screen remains open until
# this function is called or the Python program is terminated.
pyi_splash.close()
```

Comment: Where it code goes?

Comment: @Jaime, in the main file

Comment: Better to configure the .spec file properly rather then adding workarounds in the main code. Answer of @pyro is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and even though this post is old i could not find the answer :) but i was able to figure out a way to make the splash screen go away.

Once your spec file is generated using the '--splash=picture.png' modify the spec file

Parameter to mod

**always_on_top=True**  -> set to **always_on_top=False**

Then rerun the pyinstaller command using the modified spec file -> pyinstaller main.spec

Comment: The splash screen doesn't go away, it is just that your application window can open in front of it. If you move your application window you still see it.

Comment: At least this makes the splash screen go away when the application closes...

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    import pyi_splash

# your code..........

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    pyi_splash.close()

#root.mainloop()
```

See: https://coderslegacy.com/python/splash-screen-for-pyinstaller-exe/

(To run splash you must specify during pyinstaller build
`--splash=The_image_you_choose.png` #or .jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting approach could be the following. As described in the Pyinstaller documentation, the `pyi_splash` module cannot be installed by a package manager because it is part of PyInstaller, so you should put the import statement within a `try ... expect` block. However, something like

```py
try:
    import pyi_splash
except:
    pass
```

is an anti-pattern in Python.

Thus, to properly load your splash screen and having it closed when the application starts while being pythonic, you can do the following:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from ui import YourAppUI

def main():
    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()

    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    ui = YourAppUI()
    ui.show()
    with suppress(ModuleNotFoundError):
        import pyi_splash  # noqa

        pyi_splash.close()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(`# noqa` is one of those comments that can be read by your IDE to suppress warnings)

To know more about this context manager, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566001/14952856) or in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html).

Answer (score 0):

I´m using this code into my software on windows 10 (pc) and works like a charm, but using the compiled software on Windows 11 (laptop), the splash stay fixed there and wont close... the software runs under splash but can´t use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).