# Python Testing Clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm testing my python code using the Introcs package and it works fine.

But after testing my first test case it terminates giving the message **Quitting with Error**

```
import introcs
from Assignment import func_test

print("Testing function"+"\n")

test1=func_test("Hello")
introcs.assert_equals(True,test1)


test2=func_test("Hello World")
introcs.assert_equals(True,test2)
```

Here the **test2** is skipped coz the program quit with an error. How can I correct this so I can test both my test cases?

**Note:** func_test is a function that returns a boolean value depending on the string sent. But here regardless of the boolean value sent, I want both my test cases to be tested. But as soon as one fails, the following test cases are skipped.

Comment: What is `func_test`?

Comment: It's a function that returns a boolean value depending on the string sent. But here regardless of the boolean value sent, I want both my test cases to be tested. But as soon as one fails, the following test cases are skipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to ignore an exception and proceed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574730/python-how-to-ignore-an-exception-and-proceed)

Comment: Can we achieve this without using exception handling?